# Rigging - bones not properly attaching to mesh?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I just started out weight painting and the armature isn't fully connected to the mesh? i haven't finished the arm yet (as you can tell by the fingers and wrist) but if this is something that makes me start all over i wouldn't want to get too far into it.
it does this as well with every other joint... ive rigged other things before and it's never done this before so it must've been something like where i started rigging or something like that?
Thank you in advance UwU
[image: thing 1]
[image: thing 2]

Comment: It looks like this issue can be resolved by auto weight painting? Could you share the blend file and I'll have a look for you?

Comment: Ah, sorry i figure out what was the problem just now. and automatic weights pulled up an error message. But thankyou for being willing to help ^w^

Comment: okay, please answer your question or provide details of how you solved your problem so that others facing the same problem can follow it :)

Comment: The issue was that i had selected the bone in the head and weightpainted the whole body. after i got rid of all of the weight painting all of the joints rotated like the should.